# Which Object will be Garabage Collected (SCJP Book Q)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class Beta{}
class Alpha{
    static Beta b1;
    Beta b2;
}
public class Tester{
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Beta b1 = new Beta();
        Beta b2 = new Beta();
        Alpha a1 = new Alpha();
        Alpha a2 = new Alpha();
        a1.b1 = b1;
        a1.b2 = b1;
        a2.b2 = b2;
        a1 = null;
        b1 = null;
        b2 = null;
        //line 16
    }
}
```

So at Line 16 how many obj will be eligible for GC,
I think none of the object should be GC as a2 still has ref and the obj referred by a1 still has reference to beta obj.

but the answer is one obj is ready for Gc can anyone explain this

Comment: Are you sure both a1.b1 and a1.b2 should point at b1?

Comment: yes according to the Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the two `Beta` objects on the heap `Beta1` resp. `Beta2` and the two `Alpha` objects `Alpha1` and `Alpha2`.

At line 16, you have the following situation:

[image]

As you can see, `Alpha2` is reachable and through that reference `Beta1` and `Beta2` are still reachable. Thus, only `Alpha1` is eligible for GC.

Comment: You seem to have typo'd: Thus, only `oa1` a.k.a `a1`

Comment: but oa1 still has ref to ob1 then how come it can be GC

Comment: Dude Alpha2.b1 is still null ...did you mean Alpha1.b1=Beta1

Comment: No, Alpha2.b1 is the same as Alpha1.b1 (since b1 is static and shared by all objects of that class) Alpha.b1 is assigned here: a1.b1=b1;

Comment: Yep. Can't be reached (although it points at the same object as Alpha2.b1 which *is* reachable)